# How to rework addAdditionalHeaderData within TYPO3 9.5

Tags: extbase, typo3-9.x

While upgrading our codebase for 9.5 I just found the old approach with using

```
$res = $this->response;
$res->addAdditionalHeaderData('<script src="' . $scriptPath . '" type="text/javascript"></script>');
```

This all happens inside an extension controller extending ActionController, the methods seem not to exist anymore and I can't find a new way of implementing that functionality.

So how can I add additional header data inside my action controller from my extbase extension?

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

we did it with the PageRenderer class which can be instantiated within the ActionController

```
    /** @var PageRenderer $pageRenderer */
    $pageRenderer = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(PageRenderer::class);
    $pageRenderer->addHeaderData($additionalHeaderData);
```

Answer (score -1):

Since TYPO3 10.4 you have the AssetCollector class to add a Javascript or CSS. I have added this for users who find this topic at a later time.

```
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;

$assetCollector = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Page\AssetCollector::class);
$assetCollector->addJavaScript('my_identifier', $scriptPath, [], ['priority' => true]);
```

The priority must be set to true, in order to get the Javascript include into the header of the html page.